# Starting a multisite Symfony CMF Instance

Tags: symfony, web, symfony-cmf

I am checking to see if there are any recommendations on creating a multisite instance of the Symfony CMF.

My initial thoughts are to launch with Symfony 2.2 and would like to rapidly adopt the CMF once it becomes stable. If there are any known best practices to allow this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMF for now has no special support for multisite. The route document however does map the hostname field so multi-domain routing should already work.

Unless you want to mix the routes from all domains, you would want to separate the routes tree by domain and build something into the route provider to handle the domain name. A pull request on the cmf RoutingBundle would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: I thought with Symfony 2.2 so the full path can now be turned into variable(s). Does this mean the router needs to be adapted for the new change or is this something that needs to be built separately?

Comment: just stumbled over this again: most of what we need is already there with symfony 2.2 and the dynamic router supporting the hostname pattern. we might need additional things - best get in contact on symfony-cmf-devs@googlegroups.com , there is currently a discussion going on on how to do best multisites